# Как в Wordpress добавить новый раздел новостей в админке?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В WordPress есть раздел "Статьи", я хочу добавить точно такой же раздел, в который буду добавлять статьи с проектами компании, такое возможно сделать?
То есть я не хочу добавлять обычную статью с категорией "Проекты", а хочу сделать отдельный раздел, статьи которого будут относиться только к проектам.
Кто подскажет, есть такой плагин или хотя бы как сделать такое?

Comment: плагин cpt ui поставьте. Вам ниже правильно сказали

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам поможет плагин [CPT UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/). Прост в использовании, и получать данные из него с помощью WP_QUERY. Так же позволяет прикручивать таксономии и рубрики! Ваши кастомные посты появятся слева в меню в панели администратора!

Answer (score 3):

> Кто подскажет, есть такой плагин или хотя бы как сделать такое?

Это называется [кастомные типы контента](https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/#custom-post-types)

Можно [сгенерировать свой код](https://generatewp.com/post-type/) и создать на его основе [свой плагин](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Более широкие возможности управления ими дают [масса самых разных плагинов](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/Custom+Post+Types/), но нужно понимать что они пишут этот код в базу со всеми вытекающими.